# Is it true that every Banach space has Bolzano Weierstrass property?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is it true that every bounded sequence in $C[0,1]$ with sup norm has convergent subsequence? I really feel this statement is true and the crux of the proof will lie in that $C[0,1]$ is complete. But I am unable to prove it mathematically by constructing a Cauchy subsequence for any random sequence ( which will eventually be convergent). Also is my observation correct that every Banach space has this property?

Comment: Actually, not at all. The only normed vector spaces whose unit balls are compact are finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: means if X is finite dimensional then it will have BW property?

Comment: Any normed space $X$ has the BW property iff it is finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true. The sequence $f_n(x)=\sin nx$ is a uniformly bounded sequence in $C([0,1])$, but it doesn't even have a pointwise convergent subsequence, let alone one in the sup norm.

To identify families where you have a positive result, you can use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. That is, you just need to check that your family is pointwise bounded and equicontinuous.

Comment: I think $f_{n}=x^{n}$ will also work na!

Comment: Also one quick question I also asked in above comment.." can we say if X is finite dimensional then it has BW property"

Comment: @believer indeed, this follows from a finite dimensional space being isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144464/bolzano-weierstrass-theorem-in-a-finite-dimensional-normed-space for details.

Answer (score 3):

Its not true. Consider $f_k(x) = e^{i2\pi kx}$. If $k< j$ are integers, then 
 $$\|f_k-f_j\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |1 - e^{i2\pi (j-k)x}| \ge  |1 - e^{i2\pi (j-k)\frac{1}{2(j-k)}}| = 2.$$
Consequently there is no Cauchy subsequence.

Essentially the same example by thinking of Fourier coefficients - you can try the Banach spaces $\ell^p(\mathbb N)$ where now the sequence of elements $f_k \in \ell^p(\mathbb N)$ are defined by $f_k(n) = \delta_{nk}$.